# FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(439)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye

Tags: java, intellij-idea, crash

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and getting the following exception in latest version of intellij `FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(439)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.` error. This is occuring on both Ultimate and Community versions when I am opening any remote repository although new helloworld project works fine for me. I can clone the repo successfully but intellij crashes with this exception

I have also tried running intellij with `--disable-gpu` but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

disable Markdown plugin.
it's work for me.

Comment: The workaround of disabling Markdown plugin was reported in  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248140. It also worked for me so far, as of May 23rd, 2021.

Answer (score 17):

<sub>Community Edition: `211.7442.40`; Linux: `Debian 10.10`; Desktop: `XFCE`.</sub>

---

Workaround is to disable `jcef` in `vmoptions`.

Open file:

```
~/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.1/idea64.vmoptions
```

Add this line:

```
-Dide.browser.jcef.enabled=false
```

---

<sup>[[FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248140#focus=Comments-27-4625101.0-0)</sup>

Comment: This worked for me, I'm using goland and my options path is ~/.config/JetBrains/GoLand2021.1/goland64.vmoptions

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. Running it as non root user solved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

It is Electron issue, when Electron-libs don't match your system

`--in-process-gpu` option helps as workaround.
Also `--disable-gpu-sandbox` or `--no-sandbox` options helps too

Answer (score 4):

I got this message as well, I've solved it by adding to the command `--in-process-gpu`

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248140. Please try solutions from comments.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

```
$ sudo ./bin/idea.sh dontReopenProjects
```

I tried the solutions from the comments on [IDEA-248140](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248140) but it didn't seem to be related to JCEF or the markdown plugin. [dontReopenProjects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#arguments) worked for me because it stopped IntelliJ from opening a project which was causing it to crash.

All I was trying to do was update IntelliJ to the latest version as a `root` user so I just needed to get to the new/open project dialog where I could check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Running as non-root user solved the issue for me.

```
/opt/idea-IC-203.5981.155/bin/idea.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app was opening the README.MD as a default file and crashed on it. Disabling markdown plugin on your IDE or try deleting your markdown file.